# E/FirebaseInstanceId: Topic sync failed: TOO_MANY_SUBSCRIBERS error

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I get the following error regarding firebase in `logcat`:

```
E/FirebaseInstanceId: Topic sync failed: TOO_MANY_SUBSCRIBERS
there is no limit in the number of subscribers in the topic in firebase.
```

Then why firebase is giving this error? what does it mean?
I ave used my mobile number to test the firebase auth service, but I have deleted the user data from firebase and also run clean-project in android studio, but even after when I use my mobile number to verify, the above error is shown logcat.

How to solve this to get again the firebase auth OTP to verify my same number.

Comment: guide me, please!

Comment: I suggest you to add more tag that concern the problem such as firebare's one

Comment: The proble is that, I have tested firstly my mobile number to get otp via firebase auth, and got verified my number successfully, but when I have tried secondly to get otp on my used number after removing user data from firbase authenticated users and also after cleaning the android project from android studio, the above error "E/FirebaseInstanceId: Topic sync failed: TOO_MANY_SUBSCRIBERS" occurred in logcat.

Comment: So, I want to know how can I remove the user data completely from firebase so, I m able to get otp again on my same number, while according to my knowledge i have removed the data completely. And I m beginner in firebase auth service. guide me please.